# how to add a timeout for a teleop node

Tags: ros, timeout, teleop, ps3joy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a teleop node that connects with my ps3 controller wirelessly to run my robot.

I want to add a timeout feature to set all of the parameters to zero in case the joy commands stop being sent to the teleop node. I have had my robot run away on me already and don't want that to happen again.

Can someone help and provide sudo code? And would this timeout be in the main function or in the ps3 button handler?

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/50219/how-to-add-a-timeout-for-a-teleop-node/) by [mte2010](https://answers.ros.org/users/2294/mte2010/) on ROS Answers with karma: 80 on 2012-12-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-12-11**:
The general approach is to not add the timeout in the teleop node but in your robot's base node (examples: PR2, Turtlebot). The reason is that it also can happen that your network connection drops. In that case, the robot would still run away.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I create a public class variable called `double last_cmd_vel_received` that gets initialized in my constructor to `last_command_vel_received = 0`. Then, in the `main()` function of my node I read in a [ROS parameter](http://www.ros.org/wiki/Parameter%20Server) called `double watchdog_timeout`. For the main while loop I use `ros::spinOnce()` and `rate.sleep()` (where `rate` is another ROS parameter value). In my class I have a public function called `zeroVelocities()` that just sets all the actuator outputs to safe values. So, my main while loop looks something like the following:

```
...
while (nh.ok())
{
    if (ros::WallTime::now().toSec() - my_class->last_cmd_vel_received > watchdog_timeout)
    {
        my_class->zeroVelocities();
    }
    ros::spinOnce();
    rate.sleep();
}
...
```

In my callback function for the `cmd_vel` topic (where the function is part of my class) I set `last_cmd_vel_received = ros::WallTime::now().toSec()`. You can play with timeout values however you want, but I have found that `0.3` or so works well with my robots.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2012-12-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-12-11**:
A variation: save the last received message in the callback function. Then, in the loop: if (ros::Time::now() - last_msg_.header.stamp).toSec() > timeout_) { ... handle timeout ... }

**Comment by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) on 2012-12-11**:
That assumes the last received message has a header, which geometry_msgs::Twist does not (and that is what the standard cmd_vel topic publishes). But it is a viable alternative if that assumption holds.

**Comment by [Ivan Dryanovski](https://answers.ros.org/users/79/ivan-dryanovski/) on 2012-12-11**:
@Thomas D: yes, good catch.